# how to get a stdout on a batch timeout indicating that a forced exit occurred

Tags: windows, batch-file

using windows schedular, 
I am calling a batch file on windows:

```
C:\ETL\Scheduler\Schedule.bat >> C:\ETL\Logs\batchlog.log 2>&1
```

My problem is that Schedule.bat takes a really long time to run, and I have had cases where the batch file timesout.

I realize that windows scheduler will show the timeout and the close connection to the batch file,
but I'm wondering if there's a way to put in the line "forced timeout" or something similar into batchlog.log before the batch exists?

Thanks.

Comment: how about the other way round? Adding something like `Exit: Successful` at the end of the batchfile? If it's not there, it's an abnormal termination.

Comment: I'll ask.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you control timing out yourself with a second script, that runs  every minute, for example. 
It can be like this:

1) At the start of the main script a lock file is created (and deleted when script finishes)
2) the watchdog script starts and checks the lock file every minute, comparing the lock time with the current time.
3) if watchdog script sees that lock file has not been deleted after a predefined time, it terminates the main script and writes corresponding message into a log file.